# Need help to understand statement about convex polytopes

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, interpolation, convex-geometry

Statement:
Polytopes are convex, thus:
if $x, y \in P $  then $\lambda x  + (1-\lambda)y \in P$ for $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$

I understand that somehow it should mean that if we draw a line from $x$ to $y$ then it should stay inside a polytope and it won't cross the borders.

But I do not understand the formal statement. Could someone explain?
Thank you

EDIT: I guess I don't understand how  $\lambda x  + (1-\lambda)y \in P$  defines the line segment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $x,y \in P$. Look at $f(\lambda) = \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$.

Note that $f(0) = y$ and $f(1) = x$, and $f(1/2) = (x+y)/2$. As you try out different values of $\lambda \in (0,1)$ you will see that $f(\lambda)$ is indeed a parameterization of a line segment between $x$ and $y$.

Then, as you said, your statement says that if you find any pair of points in $P$, the line segment between them is also in $P$, which is a property of a convex set.

**EDIT**

To build some intuition, let $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (0,1)$. Note that 
$$
f(\lambda) = \lambda (1,0) + (1-\lambda)(0,1) = (\lambda, 1- \lambda).
$$
Notice that as $\lambda$ varies from $0$ to $1$, you begin at $(0,1)=y$ and trace out the part of the line $y=1-x$ until you end up at $(1,0)=x$. The same happens between any two pairs of points in any space, feel free to experiment with other values to get some intuition how it works.

Comment: I don't understand how  $\lambda x  + (1-\lambda)y \in P$  defines a line segment

Comment: @YohanRoth see edit for an example

Answer (score 1):

The formal statement formalize the segment between the point $x$ and $y$. As you can see in the extreme value of $\lambda$ there are point $x$ ($\lambda = 1$) and $y$ ($\lambda = 0$). And for other value of the $\lambda$ the formal statement show a linear combination of $x$ and $y$. As $\lambda$ is between $0$ and $1$, the determined point is located between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$ expresses a straight line segment, since it is the sum of a linear transformation of $x$ and a linear transformation of $y$.

And its endpoints are $x$ (at $\lambda = 1$) and $y$ (at $\lambda = 0$).

So "the line from $x$ to $y$ is fully in $P$" is precisely equivalent to the formal statement you were having trouble with.

Comment: I am sorry, but your first sentence is not an argument : if I take $\lambda x + \mu y$ with no relationship between $\lambda$ and $\mu$ I will get the whole plane generated by $x$ and $y$...

Comment: I don't understand how  $\lambda x  + (1-\lambda)y \in P$  defines the line segment

Comment: A simple reason is by writing $z = \lambda x  + (1-\lambda)y \iff z-y=  \lambda (x-y) $ (think to $\vec{YZ}=\lambda \vec{YX}$ with $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$).

Answer (score 1):

the line segment connecting two points $x,y \in R^n$ is the set

$$\{x+t(y-x) ~ | \quad t \in [0,1] \}$$ in other words: the line starting from $x$ moving toward  $y$ which is same as moving along the direction $y-x$, and stop on $y$.  and note that the later set can be rewritten equivalently as follow
$$\{tx+(1-t)y ~ | \quad t \in [0,1]\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is the polytope.

$\forall x,y \in P$ means for any $x,y$ (any two points) that are in $P$.

$\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y, 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$ is the line segement between $x$ and $y$.

Hence the statement is just what you stated, for any two points that you pick, form the line segment and the line segment should be part of the polytope.

Edit:

$\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y = y + \lambda (x-y)$,
when $\lambda = 0$, we are at $y$.

when $\lambda >0$, we are moving along the direction of $x-y$.

when $\lambda = 1$, we reach the $x$ location.

Hence it is a line segment connecting $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I don't understand how  $\lambda x  + (1-\lambda)y \in P$  defines a line segment

Comment: Edited my answer. Can you understand that part?